# Error with graphical modeler QGIS "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-modeler

I'm new to QGIS Graphical Modeler. I've used ArcMap model builder before and now trying out the Graphical Modeler in QGIS2.18.15.

I tried creating a simple model where I create a buffer for a line feature (river) and then clip point data with the newly created buffer. I want to extract the points that are located within the buffer zone.

Everything seems fine but when I hit execute I get an error: "not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Can someone please explain what does this mean and how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerAlgorithm.py", line 504, in processAlgorithm
                self.tr('Running %s [%i/%i]', 'ModelerAlgorithm') % (alg.description, len(executed) + 1, len(toExecute)))
            TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using QGIS in English or translated?

Comment: I'm using a translated version.

Comment: Which language? Does the same happen in English?

Comment: I'm using a Finnish version of QGIS. I switched it to English and the model started working without any problems! Thank you. I'm curious about why it didn't work on the Finnish version..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to fix it

This is a bug in the Finnish translation affecting QGIS up to 2.18.15.

As a workaround switch to English or update to 2.18.16.

## Explanation

The code of the modeller tries to create a message saying something like "Running (algorithm name) [50/100]". The Finnish translation provided an incomplete template for this message.

This [has been fixed now](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5d245a91e73fbb2b2f44a6d0803a4f70748e2d41) so you will be able to use any upcoming version of 2.18 (2.18.16 and up) without this problem.